# Node.js can't get post request to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to receive post requests to my server, here is the code

```
const app=express();
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const db=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');

const Product=require('./model/product');
const WishList=require('./model/wishlist');


app.use(bodyparser.json);
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.post('./product',function(req,res){
    let product=new Product();
    product.title=req.body.title;
    product.price=req.body.price;
    product.save(function(err, savedProduct){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({error:"couldnt save product"});

        }else{
            res.send(savedProduct);
        }
    });

});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Api ruunning on port 3000...")
});
```

I am using node to host my local server and mongodb for the database, when I try to use insomnia or postman to send a simple json post request to http://localhost:3000/product, they time out...

Comment: Is there an error in your logs? Would be helpful to share that info.

Comment: Aside from a warning to use useNewurlParser:true and useunifiedTopology: true, there are no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made some small mistakes like.

1. Didn't import express. Write "const express = require('express');" at the top
2. Wrong route "./product". It should be "/product"
3. app.use(bodyparser.json). It should be "app.use(bodyparser.json());"